# Updating a column GROUP BY SUM

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, sql-update, sum

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (Grp_ID int, PAmt int, Split float)
CREATE TABLE TableC (Grp_ID int,Code_ID int)
```

I want to calculate the percentage of split so that if I have one code_ID value in table C, which links to two grp_ids in tableB , It should get split up. (PAmt/SUM(PAmt)) 
In other words,

```
Case1  
INSERT INTO TableB (Grp_ID, PAmt)
VALUES (1234,2280) , (1235,3420);

INSERT INTO TableC (Grp_ID,Code_ID)
VALUES (1234,102) , (1235,102)

Expected Result:
TableB
grp_ID  PAmt Split
1234    2280  0.4  (2280 / (2280+3420))
1235    3420  0.6  (3420 / (2280+3420))

Case2 

INSERT INTO TableB (Grp_ID, PAmt)
VALUES (5174,1400) , (5175,2400);

INSERT INTO TableC (Grp_ID,Code_ID)
VALUES (5174,009) , (5175,010)

Expected Result:
TableB
grp_ID  PAmt Split
5174    1400  1 (because there is only one code for 5174) (1400/1400)
5175    2400  1 (because there is only one code for 5175) (2400/2400)



Case3 

INSERT INTO TableB (Grp_ID, PAmt)
VALUES (1111,480) , (1112,480) ,(1113,480) , (1114,960) ;

INSERT INTO TableC (Grp_ID,Code_ID)
VALUES (1111,777) , (1112,777) , (1113,778),(1114,778)

Expected Result:
TableB
grp_ID  PAmt Split
1111    480  0.50   ( 480 / (480+480))
1112    480  0.50   ( 480 / (480+480))
1113    480  0.33   ( 480 / (480+960))
1114    960  0.67   ( 960 / (480+960))
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: SQL Server 2012, Any database. How would that matters anyways?

Comment: @BhupinderSingh, it does matter since every RDBMS have their own structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard SQL99:

```
SELECT
    TableB.Grp_ID, TableB.PAmt,
    1.0 * TableB.PAmt / x.Sum_PAmt AS Split
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.Grp_ID = TableB.Grp_ID
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TableC.Code_ID, SUM(TableB.PAmt) AS Sum_PAmt
  FROM TableB
  INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.Grp_ID = TableB.Grp_ID
  GROUP BY TableC.Code_ID
) AS x ON x.Code_ID = TableC.Code_ID
```

Using window functions from SQL2003, supported by some databases:

```
SELECT
    TableB.Grp_ID, TableB.PAmt,
    1.0 * TableB.PAmt / SUM(TableB.PAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY TableC.Code_ID) AS Split
FROM TableB
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.Grp_ID = TableB.Grp_ID
```

Comment: It is giving me 0 as a result for split for all cases.

Comment: Right. `PAmt` was defined as an `int`, so the division became integer division. I added `1.0 *` to force it to `float` type. On some databases, you might need to explicitly cast it to `float` or `real`.`